# Optimal strategy for rolling die consecutively without getting a "1"

Tags: probability

Consider rolling a 6-sided die continuously and trying to tally as high a score as possible (the sum of all rolls).  If you roll a 1, then your turn is over and your score is 0.  So for each **successful** roll, the expectation value should be 4.  According to Knizia (1999), an approximately optimal strategy would be to attempt to roll to a score of 20 and then stop.  (S)he states:

> "...we know the true odds of such a bet are 1 to 5.  If you ask yourself how much you should risk, you need to know how much there is to gain.....If you put 20 points at stake, this brings the odds to 4 to 20, that is 1 to 5, and makes a fair game....Whenever your accumulated points are less than 20, you should continue throwing, **because the odds are in your favor.**"

Don't understand this, is not rolling to 20 on average essentially rolling five times (without getting a 1)?  The probability of this happening is only about 40%.  So wouldn't the odds be about 60% that you would roll a 1 and score 0 if you always try to roll up to 20?

Answer (score 8):

If your current score is $x$, you get $x$ if you choose not to roll, else if you choose to roll, your expected score based on the results of the roll is
$$\left({\small{\frac{1}{6}}}\right)(0) 
+ \left({\small{\frac{1}{6}}}\right)(x+2) + \cdots + \left({\small{\frac{1}{6}}}\right)(x+6) = \frac{20 + 5x}{6}$$
So you should continue rolling as long as 
$$x < \frac{20 + 5x}{6}$$
and you should stop if
$$x > \frac{20 + 5x}{6}$$
Thus, if your score is less than $20$, you should roll; if more than $20$, you should stop; and if equal to $20$, you're indifferent.